# I can't get past the 'list index out of range' error message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I can't get past the "IndexError: list index out of range" error message. Below is my code, and I know that the 'variant' object doen't always find a result as it may not exist but how do I stop it breaking the loop and keep searching anyway and only printing results that are found.

I have tried if statements but I must be doing it wrong.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.glenmarch.com/cars/results?make&model&auction_house_id&auction_location&year_start&year_end&low_price&high_price&auction_id&fromDate=01%2F08%2F2018&toDate=01%2F08%2F2019&keywords&show_unsold_cars=0&limit=100'

get_url = requests.get(url)

get_text = get_url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, 'html.parser')

car_listing = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "car-item"})

for cars in car_listing:
    car = cars.find('div', 'make').text
    title = car.split()
    year = title[0]
    make = title[1]
    model = title[2]
    variant = title[3]
    price = cars.find('div', 'price').text
    print(year, make, model, variant, price)
```

I am expecting to get a 'variant' result but instead it keeps breaking the code for results that don't exist.

Comment: can you post an example with all your desired fields? it looks to me that you are trying the wrong way to get info by spliting the title

Answer (score 0):

To get around errors, we can utilize a try catch statement. This waits for an error, then runs the catch statement if an error is found.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the answer you have two choices, check the length or accept there can be an error and ignore it.

```
if len(title)>3:
    year = title[0]
    make = title[1]
    model = title[2]
    variant = title[3]

#or try this
try:
    year = title[0]
    make = title[1]
    model = title[2]
    variant = title[3]
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `try...except` statement. Use it like this:

```py
try:
    '''code in which there is possibly an error'''
except:
    '''what you want to do if there is an error'''
```

`try` checks for errors and `except` does what you tell it to in case an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to **scrape** this information in the concrete auction house. This script will search for all links to `silverstoneauctions.com` and get the information from there. For other auction houses it's necessary to alter the code however.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.glenmarch.com/cars/results?make&model&auction_house_id&auction_location&year_start&year_end&low_price&high_price&auction_id&fromDate=01%2F08%2F2018&toDate=01%2F08%2F2019&keywords&show_unsold_cars=0&limit=100'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

for car in soup.select('[data-type="car_grid_item"]'):
    a = car.select_one('a[href*="silverstoneauctions.com"]')
    if not a:
        continue

    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(a['href']).text, 'html.parser')

    make = s.select_one('.lot__specification--label:contains("Make:") + div')
    print('Make:', make.text if make else '')

    year = s.select_one('.lot__specification--label:contains("Year of manufacture:") + div')
    print('Year:', year.text if year else '')

    model = s.select_one('.lot__specification--label:contains("Model:") + div')
    print('Model:', model.text if model else '')

    price = car.select_one('.price')
    print('Price:', price.text if price else '')

    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Make: Lancia
Year: 1972
Model: Fulvia
Price: £39,375
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Make: Austin
Year: 1963
Model: Mini Cooper S
Price: £65,250
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Make: Bentley
Year: 1997
Model: Continental R
Price: £39,375
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Make: BMW
Year: 1990
Model: 325i Convertible
Price: £42,188
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```